# android use html tags in textview programmatically

Tags: android, textview

I have been able to use html tags in the string ie, to set textview from resource like :

```
<resources>
<string name="somestring">
    <B>Title</B> <I>Italic</I><BR/>
    Content
</string>
</resources>
```

This works fine when the text is in resource and I set it to my textView.

Now, I want to programmatically set a string I get from server at runtime to the textView. Therefore I can't define the string in resource folder.

I tried the following

```
textView.setText("<B>Bold</B><I>Italic</I>");
```

but this doesnt work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Html.fromHtml(<String>); will work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use code like:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("YOUR HTML STRING"));
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thx for the answer I cant accept it till the next 6mins it seems

Comment: Ya no problem. you can accept it later also. important thing is that you can now go ahead in your developement.